# Can thymocytes end up in a lymph node instead of thymus?

Tags: cancer, immune-system, autoimmune, lymphatic-system

Can thymocytes exiting bone marrow end up in a lymph node instead of thymus? If not why? Here is my thought: thymocyte in the bloodstream, on its way to thymus, can leak into interstitium with blood plasma and from there enters the lymphatic capillaries that drain to the nearest lymph node.